# pi2go - move robot in 90º or move foward just 10 cm and stop?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I bought a pi2go robot, and it's fantastic, but I have some questions, I want to make the robot

1. Spin Left/Right just 90º degrees and stop
2. Move Foward/Backward just 10 cm and stop

I wanted to do 4 scripts in python just to do this like `left.py`, `forward.py`.

In the pi2go helpfiles there is a script that allows you to control the robot with the keyboard, but I don't want that I just want to call for example `sudo python left.py` one time and exit.

Here is the pi2go example :

```
import pi2go, time

import sys
import tty
import termios

UP = 0
DOWN = 1
RIGHT = 2
LEFT = 3

def readchar():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    if ch == '0x03':
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    return ch

def readkey(getchar_fn=None):
    getchar = getchar_fn or readchar
    c1 = getchar()
    if ord(c1) != 0x1b:
        return c1
    c2 = getchar()
    if ord(c2) != 0x5b:
        return c1
    c3 = getchar()
    return ord(c3) - 65  # 0=Up, 1=Down, 2=Right, 3=Left arrows

speed = 30

pi2go.init()

try:
    while True:
        keyp = readkey()
        if keyp == 'w' or keyp == UP:
            pi2go.forward(speed)
            print 'Forward', speed
        elif keyp == 's' or keyp == DOWN:
            pi2go.reverse(speed)
            print 'Backward', speed
        elif keyp == 'd' or keyp == RIGHT:
            pi2go.spinRight(speed)
            print 'Spin Right', speed
        elif keyp == 'a' or keyp == LEFT:
            pi2go.spinLeft(speed)
            print 'Spin Left', speed
        elif keyp == '.' or keyp == '>':
            speed = min(100, speed+10)
            print 'Speed+', speed
        elif keyp == ',' or keyp == '<':
            speed = max (0, speed-10)
            print 'Speed-', speed
        elif keyp == ' ':
            pi2go.stop()
            print 'Stop'
        elif ord(keyp) == 3:
            break


    pi2go.cleanup()
```

But I want to create just one script that does this and exits, like:

```
pi2go.spinLeft(100) 
pi2go.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're not giving the motors any time to turn. If I look at your code snippet, you're telling the motors to spin left, and then immediately stopping the motors.

Try doing something like:

```
import time
import pi2go

pi2go.spinLeft(100)
time.sleep(1)
pi2go.stop()
```

to give the motors time to actually do their thing.

Comment: I Will Try that, Thank you !

Comment: It Works' its the Rotors need time to respond. Thank  You !, now i need to see how much time i will put to turn just i bit left.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the initialization command `pi2go.init()`, and it looks like you also left out the all-important `import` statement that imports the `pi2go` module.

This should work:

```
import pi2go

pi2go.init()
pi2go.spinLeft(100) 
pi2go.stop()

pi2go.cleanup()
```

Obviously, I can't test this code... unless you buy me a robot. :)

Comment: I Already Tried that, but the robot don't do that, it looks that code need to be inside i while true cycle, but what i want his somethin like fire and forget. Like this :

sudo python left.py

The script runs and exits to the terminal, does not keep waiting for the next key of the keyboard.

I dont't now if i explained well

Comment: @PedroOliveira: Oh well. A `while True` loop _shouldn't_ affect anything, but maybe there needs to be some time delay, which the `readkey` stuff provides as a kind of side effect. I just noticed that your example code is broken: that `try:` statement doesn't have any matching `except` blocks. Also, I noticed I left out the `pi2go.cleanup()` call. I wouldn't think that should make a difference, but I might as well add it to my code.

Comment: Here is the Full code that i based https://github.com/the-raspberry-pi-guy/robot/blob/master/pi2go/motor.py